# intercept request headers of XMLHttpRequest javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, header, xmlhttprequest

I need to log custom request headers sent to server via all XMLHttpRequests. There are plenty of methods to intercept the request and get url parameter but could not find any describing request headers. Is this even possible ?

Any method is welcome javascript, jquery etc..

Edit: I am not permitted to change any scripts making the ajax queries. I need to intercept the queries by adding another static script.

Comment: you can wrap `setRequestHeader`, which is used to set all custom headers

Answer (score 2):

This is what **service worker** do best. Intercepts **all** requests

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('Handling request for', event.request.url);

    // Do whatever you want with request headers
    event.request.headers.forEach(function(header){

    });
});
```

The only drawback is that it's not wildly supported. And site has to be in https (service workers only works with https and http if its localhost) This is just what the feature looks like

But I can assure you that you can do it easier with [jQuery ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

Comment: For this to work the whole page has to be in https ? And is this feature supported by many browsers ?

Comment: Yepp, service workers only works with https and http-on-localhost. But today it's very encouraging to use https by default

Answer (score 0):

I think exists  some events that jquery binds on the document, like `ajaxComplete()`, so i think what you looking for is the `ajaxSend()`, I hope be useful see the snippet:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
     //this will show the url of the request
     console.log("URL", settings.url)
})
```

On the  ***settings*** parameter you can get other *header* properties.